# How to do Ifelse function in R

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
df1 = data.frame(ID=c(1121, 13345, 2234, 9954, 0092), Tr=c(3.2, "N/A", 3.3, 2.5, "N/A"), 
                 Pc=c(3.0, "N/A", 4.0, 2.5, "N/A"), TrPc=c("N/A", 3.8, "N/A", "N/A", 2.8))
```

I would like to make a new variable such that the new variable either has the average of `Tr` and `Pc` or if it doesn't have any values `N/A` it puts the numeric value of `TrPc`. I was thinking of maybe doing an `ifelse` function but I don't know how to go about it.

```
ID    Tr   Pc   TrPc  Avg
1 1121  3.2  3.0  N/A  3.1
2 13345 N/A  N/A  3.8  3.8
3 2234  3.3  4.0  N/A  3.65
4 9954  2.5  2.5  N/A  2.5
5 0092  N/A  N/A  2.8  2.8
```

Comment: What do you want to do when for example `Pc` and `TrPc` have a numeric value and `Tr` is `NA`?

Comment: (Tr == NA or Pc == NA) implies (TrPc is the Avg value)

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I would like then to only keep the TrPc grade

Answer (score 3):

`rowMeans` is a more computationally efficient solution. However, in case you are interested in the `ifelse` solution:

```
with(df1, ifelse(is.na(Tr) | is.na(Pc), TrPc, (Tr + Pc) / 2))
[1] 3.10 3.80 3.65 2.50 2.80
```

I included `with` to reduce adding the data.frame name repeatedly.

**data**

```
df1 = data.frame(ID=c(1121, 13345, 2234, 9954, 0092),
                 Tr=c(3.2, NA, 3.3, 2.5, NA), 
                 Pc=c(3.0, NA, 4.0, 2.5, NA),
                 TrPc=c(NA, 3.8, NA, NA, 2.8))
```

Comment: how come the mean for the first ID, isn't 3.10 but rather 9.6?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowMeans` after converting the `factor` columns to `numeric`

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
df1$Avg <-  rowMeans(df1[-1], na.rm=TRUE)
df1$Avg
#[1] 3.10 3.80 3.65 2.50 2.80
```

---

Or another option if we need to compare with "TrPc" column

```
pmax(rowMeans(df1[c("Tr", "Pc")], na.rm=TRUE), df1$TrPc, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 3.10 3.80 3.65 2.50 2.80
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that doesn't rely on if functions.

```
# turn numeric for calculations
df1$Tr <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$Tr))
df1$Pc <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$Pc))
df1$TrPc <- as.numeric(as.character(df1$TrPc))

# generate new variable, and replace as requested
df1$Avg <- 0
sum.has.value <- !is.na(df1$Tr + df1$Pc)
df1$Avg[sum.has.value] <- (df1$Tr[sum.has.value] + df1$Pc[sum.has.value])/2
df1$Avg[!sum.has.value] <- df1$TrPc[!sum.has.value]

# Results in:
# df1$Avg
# [1] 3.10 3.80 3.65 2.50 2.80
```